# matplotlib. legend for one curve

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, label

I am trying to make a label for a curve

```
plt.plot([1,2],[1,8])
plt.legend("some text")
plt.show()
```

However, there is only one first letter of my text in the graph:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with out passing any arguments to the `legend` function by passing a value to the label property of the plot function:

```
plt.plot([1,2],[1,8],label='some text')
plt.plot([1,2],[1,4],label='some other text')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

You can find more details on how to use `matplotlib` legends in the [legends guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html)

Answer (score 0):

`plt.plot([1,2],[1,8], label="some text")
plt.legend()
plt.show()`

Comment: I tried it. I this case graph comes without any label